# RSVP Module install error on EE 2.6.1

Tags: expresso

Trying to activate open RSVP 1.22 module on EE 2.6.1 after installing and get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Addons_modules::$channel_model

Filename: rsvp/mcp.rsvp.php

Line Number: 105


Fatal error: Call to a member function get_channel_info() on a non-object in /home/<user>/<system>/expressionengine/third_party/rsvp/mcp.rsvp.php on line 105
```

Any ideas for a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Installing latest version of RSVP (added today on Git) resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that channel_model couldn't be loaded. You should have following line of code above line of error or above line number 105.

```
$this->EE->load->model('channel_model');
```

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure what to do to fix it.  I have tried adding '$this->EE->load->model('channel_model');' to line 104, but now I just get another error:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function get_channels() on a non-object in /home/user/system/expressionengine/third_party/rsvp/mcp.rsvp.php on line 166`

Also, to clarify, this issue is happening after I install the module, and when I click the module link to 'open' the interface in CP.

Comment: This is error also seems due to not loading same model channel_model.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be happening because ExpressionEngine 2.6 doesn't load the channel model automatically.

I've just published a new version of RSVP (1.2.3) which fixes this issue:

https://github.com/expressodev/rsvp

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The updated version did the trick. All fixed now.